# How To Keep 2 Sql Server Table Colums Synced Across Different Databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a User database that is locked down to all services except the login service.  This provides a single sign on experience to all connected services.

I want to be able to access the users display name from a separate database but due to the access restrictions I need to store this information in the requesting services database.

If SecureDatabase.UserTable contains UserID and DisplayName, how can I keep this data synced with UnsecureDatabase.UserTable.

The only way I can think of at the moment is to pull a claim from the single sign on ticket when a user logs on to the website and perform an Upsert on the unsecure db, but this means the Display Name will not update in real time (And never will if the user never logs into that particular site again)

Is there a way I can achieve this in real time.  I'm running Sql Server 2014 standard.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use triggers or replication?

Comment: I did try replication but my issue was when I create a subscription it drops and recreates the table. This means it loses all indexes on it and any relationships that have been created to other tables. I'm not sure if there is a way around this? If so replication would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Transnational Replication could be used since I believe Snapshot Replication recreates the tables. If you have to use Snapshot replication, perhaps a SQL Agent job could run to recreate the relationships you need after the snapshot completes (this second scenario is probably not the best way, depending on table size, usage, etc.).

As for the Indexes, depending on how the secondary server uses the data, the indexes needed, may not necessarily be the same.

Comment: I was/am using transactional.  As the indexes copy over then I'm just making sure I create the correct indexes on the primary that are required on the secondary.  As for Relationships... this is something I'll have to live without until I figure out a way.